# How to call get value in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Below code doesn't get the value from the aura:iteration

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="item">
            <ul class="slds-has-dividers_bottom-space">
                <li class="slds-item">
                    <lightning:tile label="{!item.Contact__r.Name}">
                    </lightning:tile>
                </li>
            </ul>
</aura:iteration>
```

In Js Helper:-

```
c.set("v.contactList",storedResponse);
```

---

```
    callDetails=[SELECT Name, Contact__r.Name FROM PersonDetails__c ORDER BY CreatedDate desc LIMIT 20 ];
```

I want get the contact assoicated information but doesn't get it.

Comment: What _specifically_ is the behavior of your component? Have you debugged and inspected the values of `callDetails` and `v.contactList` and `storedResponse`? Do you observe any errors? Please [edit] your post to provide details.

Comment: I'm about 80% sure the problem is in your Apex, but without seeing more of each of your code, it's hard to tell where your problem is for sure.